# Check to see if more than one post

Tags: loop

I am new to php. I want to use a certain div "case" in the below code if there is one post here . If there is more than one I want to use another div  "case2"

```
<php>
 $connected = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
  'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
  'nopaging' => true,
) );

if ( $connected->have_posts() ) :
?>
   <?php while ( $connected->have_posts () ) : $connected->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="case"><h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php 
// Prevent weirdness
wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
</php>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to get the count of posts:

```
<?php

 $connected = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
  'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
  'nopaging' => true,
) );

echo "<h2>Found: $connected->found_posts</h2>";

?>
```

You could write a variable like:

```
$the_count = $connected->found_posts;
```

Then test with an `if`

```
if ( ( $connected->have_posts() ) && ( $the_count > 1 ) ) :
```

Comment: Pat J - you're absolutely right with the edit!